# Accidentally deleted module

Tags: android

I accidentally deleted module of my app from project structure. Is there any way how to fix it ? I wanted to delete dependency [image]

Comment: look at your physical folder in your computer. you must find it

Comment: I have it but I cannot import it

Comment: try to change it's name when you importing it